# Mysql sum balance recursively for all the hierarchy

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, union, recursive-query

I have a user table like this

| userId | username | balance | parentId | parentInfo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1000 | 0 | 0, |
| 2 | roy | 2000 | 1 | 1,0, |
| 3 | James | 2000 | 1 | 1,0, |
| 4 | Allen | 5000 | 2 | 2,1,0, |
| 5 | Nell | 4000 | 2 | 2,1,0, |
| 6 | Andy | 1500 | 5 | 5,2,1,0, |

I want to list all the users and sum of the balance for all their downline
like this

| userId | username | balance | parentId | downlineBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1000 | 0 | 14500 |
| 2 | roy | 2000 | 1 | 10500 |
| 3 | James | 2000 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | Allen | 5000 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | Nell | 4000 | 2 | 1500 |
| 6 | Andy | 1500 | 5 | 0 |

Comment: Add detailed explanations for each downlineBalance value. Especially for userId 2 - maybe it must be 10500?

Comment: sorry edited the question 
downline balance means sum of the balance for direct child, grant child, great grand child and so on,
in case of userId 2 downline balance will be 10500)

Comment: for userId 2 downline balance will be 10500
which is sum of the balance for userId 4, 5, 6 (5000+4000+1500)
where userid 4 and 5 are direct child and userid 6 is child of child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT *, parentId upperId
         FROM test
       UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.userId, cte.username, cte.balance, cte.parentId, test.parentId
         FROM test
         JOIN cte ON test.userId = cte.upperId
       )
SELECT test.*, COALESCE(SUM(cte.balance), 0) downlineBalance
FROM test
LEFT JOIN cte ON test.userId = cte.upperId
GROUP BY test.userId
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=506baa4e100d2eb76de4321343c9ba3d